# Can't copy files from Azure release pipeline to the server using FTPS

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to copy build artifacts to the external server using [FTP Upload task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) in a release pipeline. Copying them manually using `FTP` client like `FileZilla` works without problems.

However, when using the **FTP Upload task** the upload fails and I get an enigmatic error:

```
Error: Timeout (control socket)
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I'm using [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) which according to the documentation should not be a problem.

The agent that runs the job is a Microsoft-hosted agent and the server I'm trying to upload to is a where we host our website.

I'm attaching full log below. I enabled the `system.debug` flag.

```
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9607577Z ##[section]Starting: FTP Upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/***/web-app/bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9717741Z ==============================================================================
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9717997Z Task         : FTP upload
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9718049Z Description  : Upload files using FTP
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9718271Z Version      : 2.157.0
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9718589Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9718976Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload
2019-11-18T16:42:50.9719035Z ==============================================================================
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2493770Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=D:\a\_temp
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2527689Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2555912Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2819990Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e_PASSWORD
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2823414Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e_USERNAME
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2825642Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2828106Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2830125Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2831915Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2835607Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEAN
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2837936Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEANCONTENTS
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2839560Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CREDSTYPE
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2841351Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CUSTOMCMDS
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2843742Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ENABLEUTF8
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2845772Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FILEPATTERNS
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2847457Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PRESERVEPATHS
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2849535Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOTEPATH
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2851383Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ROOTFOLDER
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2853829Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVERENDPOINT
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2861900Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TRUSTSSL
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2876525Z ##[debug]loaded 18
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2884630Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2886731Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2886880Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2019-11-18T16:42:51.2887162Z ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3053978Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\FtpUpload_6f8c69a5-b023-428e-a125-fccf4efcb929\2.157.0\task.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3058819Z ##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\FtpUpload_6f8c69a5-b023-428e-a125-fccf4efcb929\2.157.0\task.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3059129Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3084503Z ##[debug]credsType=serviceEndpoint
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3086620Z ##[debug]serverEndpoint=f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3088168Z ##[debug]f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e=ftps://xxx.yyyyyyy.com:990/
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3278918Z f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e exists true
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3280524Z ##[debug]f5fb1422-e70a-49c7-a6f4-d1ce00500c9e exists true
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3282701Z ##[debug]rootFolder=D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3285478Z ##[debug]filePatterns=**
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3287739Z ##[debug]remotePath=stage
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3290201Z ##[debug]clean=false
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3291483Z ##[debug]cleanContents=true
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3292757Z ##[debug]preservePaths=true
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3294786Z ##[debug]trustSSL=true
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3296399Z ##[debug]enableUtf8=false
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3298479Z ##[debug]customCmds=passive
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3300666Z ##[debug]Searching for files to upload
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3304093Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3305105Z ##[debug]findOptions.allowBrokenSymbolicLinks: 'false'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3305244Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3305348Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3311125Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-*** (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3320759Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\1.6ab694de40eaa36ee86b.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3320965Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\10.93749650710465c7dac8.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3321457Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\2.94f04d86dbdaac2d9d59.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3321852Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\3rdpartylicenses.txt (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3322548Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\7.2d3f41ae2d147335e22c.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3323633Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\8.7e02836b7d01450732c7.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3324079Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\9.49a3d5e21ac4c61220b0.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3325323Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3330191Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3334074Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\de.json (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3334330Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\en.json (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3334695Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3339469Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3344843Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-1.jpg (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3345152Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-2.jpg (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3345412Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\logo.png (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3346517Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3352319Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\app.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3352542Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\header.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3355309Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\pages.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3360758Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\responsive.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3361082Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\sidebar.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3361675Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\spinner.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3362047Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\style.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3362250Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes (directory)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3369612Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes\bg-theme.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3369772Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\variable.scss (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3370075Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\favicon.ico (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3370852Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\index.html (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3371152Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\main.5b8add1be1fd4c5cdadf.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3372003Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills-es5.83f303640eea065cb7b4.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3372287Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills.73ec56fc41e644f4ca4f.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3373538Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\runtime.aabd127204159fb1e5bf.js (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3373879Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\styles.82712750283fab49e3e1.css (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3374783Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\web.config (file)
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3375102Z ##[debug]36 results
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3376880Z ##[debug]searching for files using: 1 filePatterns: **
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3378243Z ##[debug]Platform: 0
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3378371Z ##[debug]Candidates found for match: 36
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3378510Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3378677Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\1.6ab694de40eaa36ee86b.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3378975Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\10.93749650710465c7dac8.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3379822Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\2.94f04d86dbdaac2d9d59.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3380074Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3380471Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\7.2d3f41ae2d147335e22c.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3380947Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\8.7e02836b7d01450732c7.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3381562Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\9.49a3d5e21ac4c61220b0.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3381798Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3382083Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3382658Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\de.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3383486Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\en.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3383763Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3384026Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3384288Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-1.jpg
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3384540Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-2.jpg
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3384822Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\logo.png
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3385079Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3385348Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\app.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3385868Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\header.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3386143Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\pages.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3386402Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\responsive.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3386955Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\sidebar.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3387338Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\spinner.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3387547Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\style.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3387758Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3388133Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes\bg-theme.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3388357Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\variable.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3388553Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\favicon.ico
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3388753Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\index.html
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3388953Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\main.5b8add1be1fd4c5cdadf.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3389157Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills-es5.83f303640eea065cb7b4.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3389384Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills.73ec56fc41e644f4ca4f.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3389587Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\runtime.aabd127204159fb1e5bf.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3389783Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\styles.82712750283fab49e3e1.css
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3389960Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\web.config
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3390166Z ##[debug]searching for files, pattern: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\**
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3390561Z ##[debug]patternRoot: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3390742Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3391182Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3391363Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3391519Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3391687Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392078Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392244Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392416Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'true'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392577Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392750Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3392923Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'undefined'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3393132Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\**'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3395181Z ##[debug]expanding braces
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3397815Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/r1/a/***/web-app/bg-***/**'
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3397933Z ##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3424641Z ##[debug]35 matches
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3426069Z ##[debug]35 final results
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3426192Z ##[debug]Found total matches: 35
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3429208Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\1.6ab694de40eaa36ee86b.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3429427Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3430550Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\10.93749650710465c7dac8.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3430685Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3431701Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\2.94f04d86dbdaac2d9d59.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3431843Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3432747Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3432889Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3433699Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\7.2d3f41ae2d147335e22c.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3434082Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3434737Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\8.7e02836b7d01450732c7.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3435012Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3435617Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\9.49a3d5e21ac4c61220b0.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3435886Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3436541Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3437792Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3438177Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\de.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3438417Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3439236Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n\en.json
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3439371Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\i18n
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3439641Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3440537Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3440816Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-1.jpg
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3441095Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3441554Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background\login-register-2.jpg
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3441792Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\background
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3442289Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images\logo.png
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3442527Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\images
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3443406Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3444138Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\app.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3444442Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3444996Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\header.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3445270Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3445846Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\pages.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3446135Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3446835Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\responsive.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3447078Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3447787Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\sidebar.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3448030Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3448499Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\spinner.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3448717Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3449199Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\style.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3449418Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3450054Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3450982Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes\bg-theme.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3451111Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\themes
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3451395Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles\variable.scss
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3451635Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\assets\styles
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3452068Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\favicon.ico
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3452481Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3452928Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\index.html
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3453637Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3454257Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\main.5b8add1be1fd4c5cdadf.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3454532Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3455147Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills-es5.83f303640eea065cb7b4.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3455434Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3456038Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\polyfills.73ec56fc41e644f4ca4f.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3456319Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3457188Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\runtime.aabd127204159fb1e5bf.js
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3457423Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3457882Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\styles.82712750283fab49e3e1.css
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3458101Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3458572Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***\web.config
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3458794Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\r1\a\***\web-app\bg-***
2019-11-18T16:42:51.3488455Z connecting to: xxxxx.yyyy.com:990
2019-11-18T16:42:51.4224936Z ##[debug]Connected to xxx.yyyyyyy.com:990
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4323732Z ##[error]Error: Timeout (control socket)
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4330936Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Timeout (control socket)
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4331295Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4331723Z ##[error]Ftp Upload failed
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4332192Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Ftp Upload failed
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4332665Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Ftp Upload failed
2019-11-18T16:43:21.4422250Z ##[section]Finishing: FTP Upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/***/web-app/bg-***
```

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent? If so, is your SFTP server internet-facing? If not, this isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using a Microsoft-hosted agent and the SFTP server is the same machine that hosts our website, so its exposed to the internet. I can successfully upload the files using FileZilla client. Doing so using the same settings from Azure pipeline fails.

Comment: Hi, as I know the default FTP port is 21, while the SFTP port is 22, please check your service connection. Also, since you're using sftp, you can try using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jean-marc-ducasse.sftpupload).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not using SFTP, I'm using FTPS, there are different protocols. I'd rather not change the port, when I upload with Filezilla port 990 that I use works without any problems. I can see the connection is accepted in the server logs. So port is not an issue.

Comment: I ended up using Azure task that copies the build artifact to the `AppService` running the app. I got in touch with Microsoft support but they were unable to help me.